# Is there any method to sort a string array in specific order in java which has alphanumeric elements in it

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have an array named "testArray" with elements: {"fdvsd","sd","Edit1648004502584","zxz","automatioion","acas","teg"}

Once I use Arrays.sort(testArray), the elements are sorted as below:
{"Edit1648004502584","acas","automatioion","fdvsd","sd","teg","zxz"}

But I need the array to be sorted as follows:
{"acas","automatioion","Edit1648004502584","fdvsd","sd","teg","zxz"}

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly the issue you are having is the capitalisation of the Strings, when you want it to ignore case. Try the following code:

```
Arrays.sort(testArray, String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Or you can use `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER`.